# What is WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html in facebook login?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to integrate facebook login with my website. I am following this link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/

There, it says that " Replace YOUR_APP_ID with the app ID noted in Step 1 above and WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM with your own domain. " for the following piece of code:

```
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
  channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});
```

So my question is, what is my domain here? How can i find out what my domain is? Actually, what does this mean? Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simple. You should put or make file with name `channel.html` to your server. The contents of the channel.html file can be just a single line:

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

After you should replace `'//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html'` to full path to the file on the server. Here **//** is meant protocol instead **http://** and **https://**

Comment: I feel like the OP doesn't know what a domain actually is, which may cause further troubles as they try to build a javascript webapp

Comment: @Abbasov Alexander Does this need to be exactly like this '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html' or can it just be 'WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html' when you say full domain, is that including the levels not seen when browsing the domain via a web broswer. As in do I need to include public_html/ in this path?

Comment: @Dano007 It should with `//`. Usually, `public_html` is root directory your web server and equal `/` on the site. Example: `public_html/robots.txt` is `domain.ru/robots.txt`